# SQL Query - adding max condition for distinct name

Tags: mysql, sql

Warmest thanks by advance for your help

**My current SQL query :**

```
SELECT  
    `id`,  
    `comp`,  
    `jour`,  
    `hippo`,  
    `numcourse`,  
    `cl`,  
    `dist`,  
    `partant`,  
    `typec`,  
    `cheque`,  
    `numero`,  
    `cheval`,  
    `age`,  
    `cotedirect`
FROM `turf_12dec`.`cachedate` c
WHERE 
    `partant` > '7'
    AND `typec` = 'Attelé'
    AND `jour` > '2017-01-01'
    AND `cl` != ''
    AND `cl`!= 'NP'
```

**That I wish :**

```
AND max(jour) for distinct cheval is > '2019-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT  `cheval`
FROM `turf_12dec`.`cachedate`
GROUP BY `cheval`
HAVING MAX(`jour`) > '2019-01-01'
```

returns all the `cheval`s that you describe in your condition and you can join it to the table:

```
SELECT  t.`id`, t.`comp`, t.`jour`, t.`hippo`, t.`numcourse`, t.`cl`,  
        t.`dist`, t.`partant`, t.`typec`, t.`cheque`, t.`numero`,  
        t.`cheval`, t.`age`, t.`cotedirect`
FROM `turf_12dec`.`cachedate` t INNER JOIN (
  SELECT  `cheval`
  FROM `turf_12dec`.`cachedate`
  GROUP BY `cheval`
  HAVING MAX(`jour`) > '2019-01-01'
) tt ON tt.`cheval` = t.`cheval`
WHERE t.`partant` > '7' and
      t.`typec` = 'Attelé' and
      t.`jour` > '2017-01-01' and
      t.`cl` != '' AND 
      t.`cl`!= 'NP'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a correlated subquery:

```
and exists (select 1
            from `turf_12dec`.`cachedate`  cd
            where cd.cheval = cachedate.cheval and cd.jour > '2019-01-01'
           )
```

You don't mention the additional filtering conditions.  You may need to repeat them in the subquery as well, if they should also apply to the maximum `jour`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional filter with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  
    `id`,  
    `comp`,  
    `jour`,  
    `hippo`,  
    `numcourse`,  
    `cl`,  
    `dist`,  
    `partant`,  
    `typec`,  
    `cheque`,  
    `numero`,  
    `cheval`,  
    `age`,  
    `cotedirect`
FROM `turf_12dec`.`cachedate` c
WHERE 
    `partant` > '7'
    AND `typec` = 'Attelé'
    AND `jour` > '2017-01-01'
    AND `cl` != ''
    AND `cl`!= 'NP'
    AND (
        SELECT MAX(`jour`) 
        FROM `turf_12dec`.`cachedate` c1
        WHERE c1.`cheval` = c.`cheval`
    ) > '2019-01-01'
```

This can also be expressed with an `EXITS` condition:

```
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM `turf_12dec`.`cachedate`
        WHERE c1.`cheval` = c.`cheval` AND `jour` > '2019-01-01'
    )
```